# How to recursively resolve symlinks without readlink or realpath?

Tags: shell, posix, sh

What's the best portable (POSIX?) way to script finding the target for a link if `readlink` and `realpath` are not available?

Would you `ls -l`, and if it starts with `l` take the text after the `->` with `sed` and repeat until it no longer starts with `l` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [BashFAQ #29](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/029) (which also endorses the GNU find approach [suggested by @EugeniuRosca](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31596978/14122)):

One widely available (though not pure-POSIX) option is to use `perl`:

```
target=/path/to/symlink-name perl -le 'print readlink $ENV{target}'
```

If your symlink's name is guaranteed not to contain `->`, you can parse the output of `ls`.

---

The below code combines both approaches:

```
# define the best readlink function available for this platform
if command -v readlink >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  # first choice: Use the real readlink command
  readlink() {
    command readlink -- "$@"
  }
elif find . -maxdepth 0 -printf '%l' >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  # second choice: use GNU find
  readlink() {
    local ll candidate >/dev/null 2>&1 ||:
    if candidate=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 0 -printf '%l') && [ "$candidate" ]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$candidate"
    else
      printf '%s\n' "$1"
    fi
  }
elif command -v perl >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  # third choice: use perl
  readlink() {
    local candidate ||:
    candidate=$(target=$1 perl -le 'print readlink $ENV{target}')
    if [ "$candidate" ]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$candidate"
    else
      printf '%s\n' "$1"
    fi
  }
else
  # fourth choice: parse ls -ld
  readlink() {
    local ll candidate >/dev/null 2>&1 ||:
    ll=$(LC_ALL=C ls -ld -- "$1" 2>/dev/null)
    candidate=${ll#* -> }
    if [ "$candidate" = "$ll" ]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$1"
    else
      printf '%s\n' "$candidate"
    fi
  }
fi

readlink_recursive() {
    local path prev_path oldwd found_recursion >/dev/null 2>&1 ||:
    oldwd=$PWD; path=$1; found_recursion=0

    while [ -L "$path" ] && [ "$found_recursion" = 0 ]; do
        if [ "$path" != "${path%/*}" ]; then
          cd -- "${path%/*}" || {
            cd -- "$oldwd" ||:
            echo "ERROR: Directory '${path%/*}' does not exist in '$PWD'" >&2
            return 1
          }
          path=${PWD}/${path##*/}
        fi
        path=$(readlink "$path")
        if [ -d "$path" ]; then
          cd -- "$path"
          path=$PWD
          break
        fi
        if [ "$path" != "${path%/*}" ]; then
          cd -- "${path%/*}" || {
            echo "ERROR: Could not traverse from $PWD to ${path%/*}" >&2
            return 1
          }
          path=${PWD}/${path##*/}
        elif [ "$PWD" != "$oldwd" ]; then
          path=${PWD}/$path
        fi
        for prev_path; do
          if [ "$path" = "$prev_path" ]; then
            found_recursion=1
            break
          fi
        done
        set -- "$path" "$@" # record path for recursion check
    done

    if [ "$path" != "${path%/../*}" ]; then
      cd "${path%/*}" || {
        echo "ERROR: Directory '${path%/*}' does not exist in $PWD" >&2
        return 1
      }
      printf '%s\n' "$PWD/${path##*/}"
    else
      printf '%s\n' "$path"
    fi
    cd -- "$oldwd" ||:
}
```

Comment: Removal of `--` is necessary if `ls -- .` exits with an error. Filenames starting with dashes would not work (when not preceded with a directory name).

Comment: @user1011471, ...to be clear, by the way, it's the `--` argument to `ls`, not to `set`, which is not entirely well specified as a portability matter.

Comment: [1] There's another kind of endless loop involving 3 or more items. Should the code just give up if it hits some max number of iterations? Or is there a better way to handle this case? [2] Is there a way to refer to environments where `ls`  doesn't support `--`? Like if you were talking to someone else, is there a name for such an environment? [3] Which filenames would be affected by removing `--`?

Comment: @user1011471, I just fixed the endless-loop case. No, giving up is not needed.

Comment: @user1011471, ...re: (3), I already told you, filenames where the first character is `-`.

Comment: @user1011471, ...re: environments without `--`, I want to say that that's an XSI extension to baseline POSIX -- if it is, those would be "non-XSI" environments. However, I'd need to go read the spec to be sure.

Comment: Looked it up -- actually, as of the current revision of the POSIX specification, supporting `--` is obligatory. See Guideline 10 of the Utility Syntax Guidelines in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02

Comment: You might be misreading `prev_path` to think it only refers to the _immediately_ preceding path. It does not: It iterates through all paths stored in `$@`.

Comment: Does that have something to do with `||:`? Or: what does that mean?

Comment: I've extended this rather substantially to correctly handle relative symlinks that change directories. You're welcome. :)

Comment: The `||:` tells the shell to treat the line as not an error even if it fails (preventing automatic exit if `set -e` is in use), thus letting it declare things `local` if it supports that feature, and ignore the line otherwise. Most `/bin/sh` implementations support `local`, but the POSIX standard does not require them to.

Comment: BTW, `||:` is just the common idiom for `|| true`; `:` is a synonym for `true` (literally, calls the exact same builtin command in most shells).

Comment: I tested this in `/foo` with `2 -> subdir/1 -> target` (where `target` is in `foo` and when I was in `foo` and gave the script `2` it returned `/foo/subidr/../target` which is correct ... but does have some unnecessary path components. I am happy with it (and grateful) but wanted to point it out for completeness.

Comment: Yup. One could fix that by cd'ing to the target directory and then using PWD, but, well, one would also have to care enough to do that. :)

Comment: (That update doesn't work if the *last entry* is `/..`, but I'm convinced that that's a corner case too small to bother with).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84125/discussion-between-user1011471-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: performance: if `command readlink` is available, don't even define a shell function wrapper at all.  Then `readlink` will run the command directly.  `find` almost certainly has less startup overhead than `perl`, so unless it has some downside, I'd put `find -printf` as the 2nd choice.  And finally, `readlink_recursive` would a lot faster doing the whole thing in perl, instead of starting the interpreter once per link.  To avoid inf looping (like with `bar -> foo/bar`, where `foo -> .`, leading to `foo/foo/foo/.../bar`), limit to SYMLOOP_MAX iterations (typically 8).

Comment: @PeterCordes, we don't know that perl is available (to rely on it for recursion).

Comment: @PeterCordes, ...re: the useless shell wrapper, I define that to override any _prior_ shell wrapper; useful in testing scenarios. Given as there's no subshell involved in its invocation, the overhead is trivial.

Comment: @PeterCordes, ...your point re: order of preference is well taken, and I've adopted that change.

Comment: The failing test case re: infinite looping failure is appreciated; trailing components pointing to directories, in general, is a case I've failed to adequately handle (given as it has a very simple and elegant solution, a failure that's perhaps best remedied sooner rather than later).

Comment: @PeterCordes, ....and done: We now have a solution for that case which requires no explicit looping, relying on the operating system to provide an adequate solution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: re perl: if performance for chasing long symlink chains was an issue, you could put your `readlink_recursive` definition inside a conditional that checks for GNU `realpath`, then perl, then uses your fallback.  (`realpath` I guess canonicalizes directory components, too?)

Comment: RE: useless wrapper: yes, very minor point, but I'm weird like that and noticed it anyway :P.  For ease of testing, you could `unset readlink` in that `if` clause.

Comment: Your solution for the case of a symlink to a directory doesn't actually `readlink`, though, does it?  Bash's `$PWD` is the logical directory, unless you use `cd -P`.  Interesting idea, though, to use `cd` as an optimization for directories.  I'm not totally sure it solves the inf loop problem, though.  In my example (`bar -> foo/bar`, `foo -> .`), bar isn't a directory.  It's a symlink-loop that generates an ever-growing path, instead of ever repeating the same path.  `[[ -d bar ]]` is false, and `cd bar` gets an  `ELOOP` error message.  (`bash: cd: bar: Too many levels of symbolic links`).

Comment: @PeterCordes, on the platform where I tested, `[[ -d bar ]]` returns true, and the OS cuts that looping short (`SYMLOOP_MAX` iterations in, I'm guessing). Granted, platforms may differ, and handling the error is sensible. As for "doesn't actually `readlink`"... well, `cd` has to read the contents of the link to operate. Granted, it doesn't _canonicalize_ -- but I'm not sure that was part of the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I ran the latest and it went with the first option of using the real `readlink` but when I gave it a symlink to a directory, it returned the symlink, not the directory. But if I run `readlink` manually it returns the directory... I should add one of my uses for this is to find the real owner of the target, not the owner of the link. (And then to run the target as the real owner). I forced it to use the second option `find` and it still returns the link vs the directory. Hmm.

Comment: Easy answer there: Always readlink at least once; to ensure that, move the directory special-case handling _below_ the readlink call.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Are you sure you got the `ln -s` command in the right order?  `rm -f foo bar && ln -s foo/bar bar && ln -s . foo`.  `bar` isn't a symlink to anything but itself.  There's no directory at the end of the chain for `stat` to find.  I'm on GNU/Linux.  IDK how an infinite-loop symlink could possibly be considered a directory on any platform.  And when I said *doesn't actually `readlink`*, I mean the returned result isn't what you'd get from `readlink`.  This is what user-number-guy was reporting about it just returning its input on symlinks to directories.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it put me in `.../foo/foo/foo/foo`, but yes, it eventually stopped. And when it stopped, it was in a directory.

Comment: That's so broken!  The path doesn't even end with `bar`.  What platform is that?

Comment: Probably OS X; I'd have to go back and retest on the various systems I have access to be sure.

Comment: @PeterCordes, ...btw, if we were targeting bash rather than POSIX sh, `set -P` would be by far the easier way to work around most of the above issues.

Comment: Yeah, letting the shell do it is nice for directories.  `pushd "$d" && { pwd -P; popd; }`.  would be the best bet, IMO.  Or to avoid messing up "$OLDPWD" in a shell function: `(cd "$d" && pwd -P; )`.

Comment: I'm still not really willing to eat the overhead of forking to use command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

**LIMITATION: `-printf` is not a POSIX-specified option**

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=<symlink-name>
tmp1=''
while tmp=$(find "$tmp" -prune -printf "%l" 2>/dev/null); do
    target="$tmp1" && tmp1="$tmp"
done;
echo "$target"
```

Comment: @Charles Duffy: `-maxdepth` replaced with `-prune`. I leave this answer only for inspirational purpose, with bold limitation in header.

Comment: It's a good answer, for systems where GNU tools are available -- as I point out in my header, it's among the approaches BashFAQ #29 endorses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that is very similar to Charles Duffy's. I'm not that experienced so there may be some non-POSIX or performance issues. I arrived at this after looking at Charles' solution and replacing anything I didn't understand :-P It's very possible that after any issues here are fixed, you end up with Charles' solution all over again.

```
resolve() {
    local arg path absolute ll dir prev_path oldwd found_recursion base >/dev/null 2>&1 ||:
    arg="$1"; path="$1"; oldwd=$PWD; found_recursion=0
    dir=$(dirname "$path")
    cd -- "$dir" || {
        cd -- "$oldwd" ||:
        echo "While resolving '$arg' could not go to '$dir'" >&2
        return 1
    }
    if [ $PWD = "/" ]; then
        absolute="/$(basename $path)"
    else
        absolute="$PWD/$(basename $path)"
    fi
    [ "$path" != "$absolute" ] && set -- "$absolute"
    while [ -L "$absolute" ] && [ "$found_recursion" = 0 ]; do
        ll=$(LC_ALL=C \ls -ld -- "$absolute" 2>/dev/null)
        path=${ll#* -> }
        dir=$(dirname "$path")
        cd -- "$dir" || {
            cd -- "$oldwd" ||:
            echo "While resolving '$arg' could not go to '$dir'" >&2
            return 1
        }
        base=$(basename "$path")
        absolute="$PWD/$base"
        for prev_path; do
            if [ "$absolute" = "$prev_path" ]; then
                found_recursion=1
                break
            fi
        done
        set -- "$absolute" "$@"
    done
    if [ -d "$absolute" ]; then
        cd -- "$absolute" || {
            cd -- "$oldwd" ||:
            echo "While resolving '$arg' could not go to '$absolute'" >&2
            return 1
        }
        printf '%s\n' "$PWD"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$absolute"
    fi
}
```

Edit: now using `$PWD` and `printf`, canonicalize result if directory.

Comment: `$(pwd)` is much less efficient than `$PWD`, since -- like any `$(...)` expansion -- it forks off a subshell, runs an operation in that subshell, reads its stdout, waits for it to exit, and substitutes that output.

Comment: Also, you have bugs around quoting. `$(basename $path)` breaks badly when `path` contains spaces. At least use `$(basename "$path")`, though that's still much less efficient than the equivalent parameter expansion.

Comment: Also, making nontrivial use of `echo` is bad form -- what echo does varies wildly from platform to platform. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html: Some versions of `echo` (POSIX+XSI) expand backslash expansions by default; on some, the behavior of backslash expansions is undefined; behavior when handling a string containing only `"-n"` is undefined; handling of a string `-e` **is** standard-defined (a conforming implementation must print `-e` on its output), but some implementations, including bash, don't comply with the standard in that respect.

Comment: Otherwise, though, this isn't awful. Because it always uses `ls -ld`, instead of preferring GNU find or perl when available, it can't correctly handle symlinks containing ` -> ` in their names, and behavior with unprintable characters inside link targets may be broken, but if you're only trying to deal with well-behaved filenames (lucky you!), that may be acceptable.

Comment: Speaking of performance -- I've updated my version to run the tests to determine the best available readlink implementation only once, before defining the function, rather than doing so every time readlink is called.

Comment: As an aside, PeterCordes found a significant bug in the logic of my original which could lead to an infinite loop; you might consider updating this derivative to incorporate its fix.