# In shell, check what /bin/sh is symlinked to

Tags: linux, shell

In Shell script, How can I check if `/bin/sh` is softlink'ed to `dash` or `bash`, I may have `/bin/sh -> dash` or `/bin/sh -> bash`

Comment: In general, btw, even if `/bin/sh` is linked to bash, your code should work as if it were linked to dash anyhow. Bash doesn't promise to provide anything more than minimum POSIX sh functionality when invoked under the `sh` name [though in practice it does, to an extent that varies across releases], so any script using a `#!/bin/sh` shebang should be written to function properly with that functionality alone.

Comment: Thanks Charles, yes its a duplicate, sorry, the other answer helped me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596363/how-to-recursively-resolve-symlinks-without-readlink-or-realpath/31597888#31597888, btw, is also relevant to being able to what `readlink` does without actually *having* `readlink` (includes various fallback implementations, including GNU `find`, `perl`, or even ultimately `ls -l`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to print the filename your symlink is pointing to:

```
readlink -f $(command -v sh)
```

or using `stat` command:

```
stat -c '%N' $(command -v sh)
```

Comment: `which` over `command -v`? (The latter is actually mandated by current POSIX; the former is just... frequently available, AFAIK).

Comment: Good point about `command -v` (edited)

Comment: ...hmm. I wonder if I should add `stat -c` to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596363/how-to-recursively-resolve-symlinks-without-readlink-or-realpath/31597888#31597888. OTOH, any platform with GNU stat will presumably also have GNU find, and thus be already covered.

Comment: Yes indeed `find` should be available if gnu `stat` is available.